# How to create ImageDescriptor object for an image outside the Workspace?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my project, there are two types of applications:

1. A windows application (W-app), which will be installed to the
   system.
2. Eclipse Application (E-app), which is a Plugin packaged
   application.

My scenario is like E-app has to use icons from the installed folder of the 'W-App' (Say C:\Program Files\W-app\Icons).

As these images are frequently used, I thought of creating the 'ImageRegistry'.

For creating the ImageRegistry, I need the ImageDescriptor objects.

How to create ImageDescriptor object for an image outside the Workspace ( from the installed directory of W-app'?

Comment: If your images are bundled with the application and don't change (e.g. a logo or a disk image for a 'Save' button) a portable way of storing and loading is to put them on the class path. Then you can use `ImageDescriptor.createFromURL( Images.class.getResource( "foo.png" ) );` to load an image and `Image` can be any class that lies in the same package as the resource to load.

Comment: Rüdiger Herrmann: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Rüdiger Herrmann: Thanks for the reply. But, I'm only having the test data. So, I'm unable to do this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```java
ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(null, "full path of file");
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. "Full path of the file" means "The absolute path of the file" right?

Comment: Sorry I could not vote up, as I need atleast 15 reputations. But, your answer works.

Comment: Yes, the absolute path.